# How to auto focus on a newly created input. DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have this:

`var newthing = document.createElement("input");`

How would I be able to force the user to automatically select/focus on that input?

Comment: First you'd have to add that new element to your document, then call `focus()` on it. eg `document.body.appendChild(newthing); newthing.focus()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you just gotta focus on the element...

```
newthing.focus()
```

that should do it... here is [some docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus)